# Not being able to write output to text file

Tags: c#, io

Please suggest whats wrong with the following code to write names to text file. The file is being created but nothing is written in it. Although program is running fine and there is no exception yet not getting anything in txt file.

```
class IO
{
    public void write(string name)
    {
        try
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"D:\Infogain\ObjSerial.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            sw.BaseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Current);
            sw.Write(name);
            fs.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Issue in writing: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string name;
        int ch;
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        do
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter name");
        name = Console.ReadLine();
        IO io = new IO();
        io.write(name);
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 to continue");
        ch = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }while(ch==1);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please tell us what's going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should read up on Object Oriented Programming a little. Creating a new IO object within that loop makes no sense. Also your write function is kind of messed up.

Fixed version:
(note: "write" function appends to file)

```
public class IO
{
    public static void write(string name)
    {
        try
        {
            string path = @"e:\mytxtfile.txt";
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(name);
            }   
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Issue in writing: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string name;
        int ch;
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter name");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            write(name);
            Console.WriteLine("Enter 1 to continue");
            ch = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        } while (ch == 1);
    }
}
```